# Next version of jQuery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know what's going to be in the next version of jquery (1.3.3 and 1.4) and if there's a place where we can follow its development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_1.4_Roadmap

Answer (score 2):

The best place is the [jQuery-Dev](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev) mailing list, since it centers around the current development of the jQuery library itself.

You may want also to give a look to the [SVN repository updates](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/updates/list).